# React-Hook-Form is showing required type error, even though the field is populated

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, react-forms

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I have a problem on validating three input fields. Two of them are working properly! But the phone number one is showing the required type error even though I populate it.

The code snippet is below:

```
<Controller
  control={control}
  name='phoneNumber'
  render={({ field }) => (
    <Input {...register("phoneNumber", { 
      minLength: { value: 7, message: "mínimo de 7 caracteres" }, 
      required: { value: true, message: "campo obrigatório" }
      })} 
      name="phoneNumber"
      onChange={handlePhoneNumberChange} 
      value={inputPhone} 
      invalid={errors.phoneNumber && true}
    />
  )}
/>
```

The other two that are working follow this example:

```
<Controller
  defaultValue=''
  control={control}
  name='confirmPassword'
  render={({ field }) => (
    <Input  
      {...register("confirmPassword", { required: true,  minLength: 8 })} 
      type='password'
      placeholder='Digitar senha novamente'
      invalid={errors.confirmPassword && true} 
      {...field} 
    />
  )}
```

Down below is the detailed info about the handlePhoneNumberChange function and the format function. They are there so that I can format the phone number that is populated in the Input field

```
export default function FormatPhone() {

  const { register, handleSubmit, control, formState: {errors}} = useForm()

  const [inputPhone, setInputPhone] = React.useState("")
  const [phoneNumberLength, setPhoneNumberLength] = React.useState(0)

  

    const formatPhoneNumber = (value) => {
        if (!value) return value
        const phoneNumber = value.replace(/[^\d]/g, "")
        const phoneNumberLength = phoneNumber.length
        if (phoneNumberLength < 4) {
          setPhoneNumberLength(phoneNumberLength) 
          return phoneNumber 
    }
        if (phoneNumberLength > 7) {
          setPhoneNumberLength(phoneNumber)
          return `(${phoneNumber.slice(0, 2)}) ${phoneNumber.slice(
            2,
            7
          )}-${phoneNumber.slice(7, 11)}`
        }
      }
      const handlePhoneNumberChange = (e) => {
        const formattedPhoneNumber = formatPhoneNumber(e.target.value)
        setInputPhone(formattedPhoneNumber)
```

Comment: There's not enough context here to help. Unrelated, but what's the point of `&& true` in the `invalid` properties?

Comment: What do you need more about the context?  The && true makes sure the expression inside invalid is truthy when there is an error so that invalid field property will be truthy, and then it will be shown an invalid icon on the input field. Invalid is a property from "reactstrap" lib in the built-in Input component.

Comment: (I just use `!!` if I need a strict boolean, but :shrug:) We don't know anything about  `handlePhoneNumberChange` or `inputPhone`, and the phone number and password fields aren't equivalent *(there's no value from (state?) for the password)*. They're not equivalent so there's no point in comparing them.

Comment: just updated the question with the info you wanted

Comment: [Please post text, not images.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Well, now here we go